# npm WARN cannot run in wd example@0.0.1 npm run install-submodules

Tags: node.js, npm

I get the following error when I run npm install

```
npm WARN cannot run in wd example@0.0.1 npm run install-submodules
```

Here's my install-submodules script

```
"install-submodules": "git submodule foreach --recursive 'if [ \"$name\" != \"example/dcx\" ] ; then npm install; fi'",
```

Has anyone seen this error?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue.